# bad value in range argument error - regarding range construction in ruby

Tags: ruby, range, irb, argument-error

I wrote the following snippet.

```
def add_me(num)
    result = 0
    (1..num).each { |i| result += i}
    result
end
puts add_me(STDIN.gets)
```

I received an argument error `list_sum.rb:6:in 'AddMe': bad value for range (ArgumentError)`  the line # corresponds to line # in my editor.

I also experimented with things like `foo = (1..num).to_a`.  But still receive the same error.  What is going on?  Ruby version 2.3.3.  What am I missing?  I should be able to use variables in ranges, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets` returns a string. You need to do `gets.to_i`, in order to turn the input into a number for your numeric range. Right now you’re trying to make a range where the start is the number 1 and the end is some string, and that is raising an `ArgumentError`.

Also as an aside, ruby convention would tell you that your function should be named `add_me`. Ruby uses snake case, and anything that starts with a capital letter is typically assumed to be a class or constant (constant being all caps).

Comment: works now.  BUT if input is  `integer n` is it not an integer by definition?( IE regex /d+/ would pick up [0-9])

Comment: Nope. `gets` always returns a string. There’s a big difference between “5” and 5. It may help you to try out `puts gets.class` and then `puts gets.to_i.class`. Be sure to type the exact same input both times. You’ll see that the first one outputs `String`, and the second puts either `Integer` or `Fixnum` depending on your ruby version (Fixnum as been deprecated in favor of Integer).

Comment: Another thing you may want to try is ditching the gets for a second and doing `AddMe(5)` and then `AddMe('5')`. You’ll find that the first one works fine, and the second errors the exact same ArgumentError as before. Hopefully that’ll help you understand what’s going on more.

Comment: u r right. `gets.class i` returns `String` in irb. Never tried it before.  `Fixnum` for`gets.to_i.class` perhaps I should update irb from v 0.9.6

Comment: There is no need to update IRb. That will not change anything. `gets` will *always* return a string. That's what it does. That's what the documentation says. Guess what the `s` in `gets` stands for?

Comment: Right. This is not an IRB issue. This is just how Ruby works. `gets` always returns a string. If you need it to be something else (like a number), you’ll have to convert the value.